# How to properly call an external WCF Service from SharePoint 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to call an external WCF Service from within SharePoint. Using normal WCF calls immediately causes a `SocketException` (An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host), which can be circumvented with `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatePrivileges`.

> [SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
>      System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) +85
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing) +204
>
> [CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:58.7210000'.]
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing) +15307563
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout) +90
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout) +34
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout) +34
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +88
>      System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +58
>      System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +62
>      System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +54
>      System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +402
>
> [IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception.]
>      System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +704
>      System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +154
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout) +87
>
> [CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:58.7210000'.]
>      System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +10257978
>      System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +539
>      MyApp.FunctionThatCallsService()

That got me thinking: SharePoint does it, and they do it in a nice way where they have individual service configurations in `14\WebClients`.

I reflected and cloned a lot of it (The Extension Methods on the ChannelFactory are used internally all over the place - [SPChannelFactoryOperations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spchannelfactoryoperations.aspx)), but I wonder: Are the "proper" APIs that SharePoint uses to call it's own WCF Services exposed to external code, so that I can call my non-SharePoint WCF Services from custom SharePoint code?

(This is a farm solution deployed to the GAC, so neither CAS nor Sandboxing applies)

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2007 or 2010?

Comment: disregard I saw the tag... better questions to follow.

Comment: I think if you are getting a security exception then perhaps the user context that SharePoint uses to call your external service doesnt have the proper authorization to connect.  Where and with what security settings is your WCF Service deployed?  Are you constructing the endpoints and bindings in code or have you altered the SharePoint servers web.config?

Comment: @Glenn I'm getting a security exception even when running as Farm Administrator level. My WCF Service is on another machine in the same domain and uses Windows Authentication. Both my and the Sharepoint Farm account can connect to it just fine. If I call from SharePoint, I get the exception, unless I use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Comment: You can use Business Connectivity Services (BCS) for connecting to your WCF service check this simple article [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953200.aspx)

Comment: What function does your WCF service provide? if it is bringing additional data into SharePoint for consumption, you should consider creating a 'external content type' and BCS (business connectivity services).  This is the preferred method for interoperating with external data.

Comment: Actually it's a SocketException, my bad. Added the call stack.

Comment: @Glenn It's custom functionality that Web Parts and User Controls use, for example a customized Navigation and external user settings. BCS would be a big stretch, not to mention the excessive and arcane plumbing required for it.

Comment: This appears to be a timeout issue that can be mitigated with the correct binding.  are you setting the WCF Address and Binding in code or in the web.config?

Comment: No, it's instantly closing the connection, it's not a timeout. The WCF Config is loaded from an external .config file, but moving it into the web.config OR creating the binding in code doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up keeping the `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` section. Microsoft's `SPChannelFactoryOperations` at some point hit a NullReferenceException, most likely due to Claims required to be setup within the service even when not using it (`SPServiceAuthenticationMode` only has `SPServiceAuthenticationMode.Claims` as a member. The fact that `CreateChannelActingAsLoggedOnUser()` immediately throws an ArgumentException is a signal that the `SPChannelFactoryOperations` aren't meant to be used by non-Microsoft code.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying to ignore certificates.

http://www.fryan0911.com/2006/07/vbnet-how-to-accept-web-service-ssl.html

Perhaps you need a proxy? Are you having some type of port block problem?

Comment: It's not using SSL, just straight http or net.tcp. Ports are open - if I move the WCF Call inside a SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges block then everything works as expected.

Comment: Perhaps a credential issue. When you run with elevated privledges your credentials are the app pools. How did you reference the WCF? Are you adding a service reference or creating a proxy class? I recommend trying to create a proxy class using wsdl.exe and seeing if that fixes it. Run VS 2010 Command Prompt as admin and see here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.80).aspx